# Django Model, Referenced via Text Fields (without the fields ending in '_id')

Tags: python, mysql, django

I am inheriting a poorly designed DB as I port code from PHP to Django/Python.  Redesign the database is a constraint on this project, and as such is off the table completely.  I have two tables that are referenced via a text field

```
class MemberCompany(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    company_name = models.TextField(blank=True)
    ticker = models.CharField(max_length=45L, blank=True, unique=True)
    primary_address = models.TextField(blank=True)
    industry_classification = models.TextField(blank=True)
    website = models.TextField(blank=True)
    industry_id = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    business_description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    dodilio_class = models.TextField(blank=True)
    category_id = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    parent_industry_id = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=20L, blank=True)
    country_listing = models.CharField(max_length=255L, blank=True)
    exchange = models.CharField(max_length=45L, blank=True)
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'member_companies'

class TeaserTickers(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    teaser = models.ForeignKey(Idea, related_name='tickers')
    ######################################################v
    # This works to return the ticker text
    #ticker = models.CharField(max_length=135L, blank=True)
    ######################################################v
    # This returns: "Unknown column 'teaser_tickers.ticker_id' in 'field list'"
    #ticker = models.ForeignKey(MemberCompany, to_field='ticker')
    ######################################################v
    # This returns: "Unknown column 'teaser_tickers.ticker_id' in 'field list'"
    ticker = models.ForeignKey(MemberCompany, to_field='ticker')
    date_added = models.CharField(max_length=135L, blank=True)
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'teaser_tickers'
```

How do I form a foreign key relationship between the two tables / model classes if the database doesn't follow the django naming convention.

I tried defining my own relationship, but that had issues too (for some reason it wasn't querying MemberCompany and instead was attempting to push the ticker value (e.g. 'AAPL') onto a stack of MemberCompany.  But here is the code for that:

```
class ImproperlyNamedForeignKey(djangoRelated.ForeignKey):
    def get_attname(self):
        return self.name
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be this would help:

```
ticker_id = models.CharField(
    max_length=255,
    blank=True,
    db_index=True,
    db_column='ticker'
)
ticker = models.ForeignKey(MemberCompany, to_field='ticker')
```

If this doesn't help, please consider these useful links:

- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/legacy-databases/
- http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter18.html